# query design with grouping

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm having trouble coming up with a working query for this situation...

**Table:**

```
[ matchID ]  [ User ] [ team ]
     1          10       1
     1          77       2
     2          10       1
     2          77       1
     3          10       2
     4          10       1
```

**Notes:**

- sometimes the opponent is unknown, for example in matches 2, 3, and 4
- sometimes a team has only one person on a side, for example match 1
- sometimes a team has n persons on a side, for example match 2

**Desired Query Results:**

A list of matchIDs for a given user where the opponent is unknown.

My first attempt was:

```
SELECT matchID FROM table
GROUP BY matchID
HAVING COUNT(matchID) = 1
```

but then I realized that I wasn't counting matches where there are teammates but unknown opponents, such as match 2 above.

In plain English, I need to get all matchIDs where:

- involving a given user **<- edited to add**
- everyone is on the same team
- OR there is only one person listed

but I'm not sure how to do that efficiently in one query. Help?

Comment: how does match 1 have "one user on a side"?

Comment: @davogotland "one user *per* side", I think.

Comment: yep, in match 1, team 1 has only one member - user 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MatchID
  FROM Table
 GROUP BY MatchID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Team) = 1;
```

You seem to need those matches where only one team is recorded in the table, and this query gives you those matches.

If the match must involve a specific user (10 for the sample data), then:

```
SELECT t1.MatchID
  FROM Table AS t1
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT *
                FROM Table AS t2
               WHERE t2.UserID = 10 AND t1.MatchID = t2.MatchID)
 GROUP BY t1.MatchID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.Team) = 1;
```

You can probably do that as an (inner) self-join:

```
SELECT t1.MatchID
  FROM Table AS t1
  JOIN Table AS t2 ON t1.MatchID = t2.MatchID AND t2.UserID = 10
 GROUP BY t1.MatchID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.Team) = 1;
```

Or, perhaps a little more clearly:

```
SELECT t1.MatchID
  FROM Table AS t1
  JOIN (SELECT MatchID FROM Table AS t2 WHERE t2.UserID = 10) AS t2
    ON t1.MatchID = t2.MatchID
 GROUP BY t1.MatchID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.Team) = 1;
```

The sub-select picks those matches where UserID 10 played; the rest works as before.

Comment: sorry gentlemen, I forgot one requirement. Stated at the top but omitted from the bottom of the question. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of teams per match. If there's only one then there's not enough:

```
SELECT matchID 
FROM table
GROUP BY matchID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(team))=1;
```

Comment: sorry gentlemen, I forgot one requirement. Stated at the top but omitted from the bottom of the question. Please see the edit.

Comment: Oh well, it seems we can both be misled by the example proto-query which didn't attempt to address a condition that was mentioned in passing in the question. :(

Answer (score 0):

you haven't provided a table name, so i have decided to call it `mut` as in short for matches users teams. anyways, this seems to be working on all cases:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `matchID`
FROM
    `mut`
WHERE
    `user`=10
AND
    `matchID` NOT IN (
        SELECT
            `m1`.`matchID`
        FROM
            `mut` AS `m1`
        INNER JOIN
            `mut` AS `m2`
        ON
            `m1`.`matchID`=`m2`.`matchID`
        AND
            `m1`.`team`<>`m2`.`team`
    )
```

Comment: oops, that one had a bug. edited it now. i also added one row: `match 2, user 30, team 2`. this makes it so that there are 2 players on team 1 and 1 player on team 2 in match 2. so new player 30 and good ol' 77 has no matches with unknown opponents, and player 10 has unknown opponents in matches 3 and 4. without that row, player 77 has unknown opponent in match 2.

Comment: 19 lines of SQL where 10 would suffice seems unnecessarily profligate on the vertical space and (to my eyes) hinders the readability of the SQL.

Comment: This seems to scan the table 3 times (once for each FROM or JOIN), which is likely to be less efficient than doing so only twice.